# How to build and run BIRT source in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, birt

I was able to pull the BIRT source (4.2.2 branch) from here: https://github.com/eclipse/birt/ using m2e (Maven integration for Eclipse) and imported it in my eclipse workspace. The BIRT documentation (https://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Birt_Project#Q:_How_to_Build_BIRT_3.7.1.2B_from_GIT.3F) seems to be outdated. As a result, I'm having many issues building the source.

My question is: Can anyone explain to me how I can build the 4.x source using Eclipse?

Here are what I use:

1. Eclipse EE Mars
2. Egit plugin
3. m2e plugin (Maven Integration for Eclipse)
4. Java 1.5/6/7/8

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. The answer is in the page you linked to =/ https://github.com/eclipse/birt/#building-birt

Comment: @Tunaki: The description does not work. It results in build errors.

Comment: Can you post your logs then? Along with the command that you ran?

Comment: Did you try BIRT version 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is, after importing the project in your eclipse workspace, run below maven command to make it compatible with Eclipse,

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This will solve your eclipse and maven dependecy errors.

Also you can check whether the problem is with your imported project , i.e. missing any libraries or just with eclipse.

You can try to build the project from command prompt to check the same with

```
mvn clean install
```

Once done refresh the eclipse workspace.

**Note: Run the commands from the place where your pom.xml resides.**

Comment: do I need to use a concrete version of maven? I get build errors even on "clean": "cannot resolve dependencies..."

Comment: By default eclipse uses its internal maven. You can download latest maven from [link](https://maven.apache.org/) and configure the same in eclipse. And for the errors can you provide the logs and pom.xml to narrow it down further?

Comment: I tried building it from the commandline. Are you able to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set jre 1.7 and not jdk. 
from command line go to the pom.xml directory and run

```
mvn package -Pmars -DskipTest
```

Comment: Sorry I meant jre 1.7, can you refer to this link:http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/925-using-birt-430-with-maven/

Comment: that somehow worked! can you explain why it does not compile with java 1.8?

Comment: mostly the BIRT project is faceted/compiled with 1.7